# Getting random data from database with conditions

Tags: java, android, database, random

so here I'm trying to get a random question from my table where the column "stat" is 0, anyway the problem here is that it won't accept the random int so c.moveToPosition(rnd) makes the error or I don't now and it causes the app to crush. This's the code please help!

```
public String[] databasetostring ()  {
    String dbstring = "";
    String optstring = "";
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_QUESTIONS + " WHERE 1";

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    c.moveToFirst();

    while (!c.isAfterLast()){
        if (   c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("stat")) != 1   ){
                dbstring += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("question"));
                dbstring += "\n";
                optstring += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("answer"));
                optstring += "\n";

        }
        int rnd = new Random().nextInt(c.getCount());
        c.moveToPosition(rnd);
    }
    db.close();
    c.close();
    return new String[] {dbstring, optstring};

}
```

This is the logcat, it keeps going into that loop!

```
07-29 22:40:07.352  10939-10949/com.example.bibiwars.digital D/dalvikvm GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 23% free 6057K/7824K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
07-29 22:40:07.352  10939-10939/com.example.bibiwars.digital D/dalvikvm GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2061K, 49% free 3995K/7824K, paused 0ms, total 0ms
07-29 22:40:07.362  10939-10939/com.example.bibiwars.digital D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 39% free 4820K/7824K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
07-29 22:40:07.362  10939-10939/com.example.bibiwars.digital D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 824K, 34% free 5232K/7824K, paused 0ms, total 0ms
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you kinda crude way to implement such stuff.
Try getting all ques as string in (say) ques[] and corresponding options in opt[]. Then, get the size of the ques[] which corresponds to total number of questions you have. Now, select a random number b/w [0,count) and use it in your application.
You can now keep a flag of asked ques if you want, using a bool flag[] of equal size.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, c'mon man... This is one that always works. Its basic logical implementation. If you have code in which you implemented this method, post it here and I shall help or maybe I give you a pseudocode.

Comment: Listen the database I have was filled from arrays within the app so I just changed cursor by the random only and it works but in my case I need to use the cursor for other perposes, so I tried the cursor and it does not work in this case !!

Comment: ok...So, tell me one more thing. Do you want to randomly arrange the questions (and use all questions) to show to user?

Comment: See this link here. It should help: [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28%29)

Comment: yeah but the questions shall be displayed 1 by 1.

Comment: Random().nextInt(int n) does not guarantee a random permutation of numbers in [0,n), so it might be the case that '1' is never being selected again. Use some other random generator function or a custom implementation using a bool visited[] array or something.